Study of model reaction HCl + NH3 in water
I'm a student, and I've been given the neutralization reaction between $HCl$ and $NH_3$ to study. It Is asked to calculate how much acid is necessary to add to a $NH_3$ solution to make all the ammonia become it's conjugated acid.
These are the reactions I think I managed to identify that are happening inside the solution:

The strong chloridric acid, totally dissociates (there is no equilibrium as the acid is strong):

$$HCl + H_2O \longrightarrow Cl^- + H_3O^+$$

The ammonia partially reacts with water, forming it's conjugated acid (there is equilibrium):

$$NH_3 + H_2O \Longleftrightarrow NH_4^+ + OH^-$$

The ammonia partially reacts with the ion $H_3O^+$, produced by 1) (there is an equilibrium)

$$NH_3 + H_3O^+ \Longleftrightarrow NH_4^+ +  H_2O$$
(4). The chloridric acid reacts with the $OH^-$ produced by 2))
$$HCl + OH^- \longrightarrow Cl^- + H_2O$$
The full complete reaction is:
$$HCl + NH_3 + H_2O \longrightarrow NH_4^+ + Cl^- + OH^- + H^+ \longrightarrow NH_4Cl_{(aq)}$$
Now, assuming this model is correct (which I'm not sure anyways), I have some questions:

How can the $NH_3$ be consumed totally if the only processes that involve it are processes at equilibrium (which therefore have to maintain a certain equilibrium between the consumed reagents and the formed products?

How is it possibile for the two reactions that involve $NH_3$ alone to be processes at equilibrium, while the full reactions is not?


To me, it seems that inside the full reactions it is implied that there are as many $OH^-$ as $H^+$, which are going to form water following:
$$H^+ + OH^- \longrightarrow H_2O$$
whereas the production of $H^+$ by the chloridric acid is complete (the acid is dissolved entirely) while the production of $OH^-$ comes from a process at equilibrium. Refrasing the question: how can it be that 1 mole of $H^+$ reacts precisely with one mole of $OH^-$, thus letting us removing it from the complete reaction, while $H^+$ and $OH^-$ are produced by processes that do not guarantee that they are in 1:1 correspondence?
Thank you in advance!

Guides for formatting of chemical/mathematical formulas/expressions/equations: Basics / Detailed / Upright vs Italics / Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

The term "chloridric acid" was common in the 19th century,  probably based on French "acide chlorhydrique". English uses for quite long time "hydrochloric acid".

Sorry, I'm Italian. Here we call It "Acido cloridrico", which I thought would translate to "chloridric acid"

If you agree that H2O reacts completely and irreversibly with HCl, then HCl must react completely and irreversibly with NH3, since NH3 is a stronger base than H2O

@unstable As gases or liquids then yes. In water, HCl reacts (approximately) completely with water, and then H+(aq) incompletely with NH3, being much weaker acid than HCl.

I think that the reaction between ammonia and $\ce{H3O+}$ is not appreciably reversible and thus drives the total reaction to "completion." To be honest, this is an oversimplification, but for the sake of clarity:
Assume that:
$$\ce{NH3 + H3O+ <=> NH4+ +H2O}$$
then;
$$K= \frac{\ce{[NH4+][H2O]}}{\ce{[NH3][H3O+]}}=\frac{\ce{[NH4+][H2O]}}{\ce{[NH3]}\frac{k_w}{\ce{[OH-]}}}=\frac{k_b(\ce{NH3})}{k_w}\ce{[H2O]}\approx 1.8\cdot 10^9 \ce{[H2O]}$$
To ensure that the reaction goes to completion, provided that you have all the initial concentrations and all the equilibrium constants, you should try to write the balance equations for this system in order to obtain the polynomial equation of n-th order that describes the concentration of a certain species once complete equilibrium is obtained. If you observe, in the process of deriving the equations, that certain constants are too high or too small, you can make approximations, but given the invention of computers, I suggest you just set up the complete equations and solve them.
If you are Italian, you can look for a good book called "Chimica Analitica" written by De Simoni, and another one called Quantitative Analytical Chemistry by Harris.
